# How to decode URL entities in iMacros URL extraction?

Tags: urlencode, imacros, urldecode

I write some infos with the current URL into a csv-file with imacros. The URLs are written with

```
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=+{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
```

After i open the csv file in Excel (open an empty Excel file, then import data from text (my csv) file) everything is OK, but if there are any entities in the URL, they are encoded like https://www.google.de/search?q=g%C3%83%C2%BCnstig%20%C3%83%C2%BCbernachten.

How can i adjust the iMacros code to write URLs and /or save the csv file with decoded URL entities?

I guess it could be possible to run something like `decodeURIComponent` or even something like [this](https://goo.gl/NCjtX8) inside of iMacros, but don't know the right syntax for such implementations. My try to replace

```
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
```

with

```
SET !VAR2 decodeURIComponent ({{!URLCURRENT}}) 
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR2}}
```

or

```
SET !VAR2 unescape ({{!URLCURRENT}}) 
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR2}}
```

don't work:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("decodeURI('{{!EXTRACT}}');")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=+{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
```

(However Microsoft Excel may not support UTF-8 encoding. So, open it with something like ‘Notepad’.)